# bss section size calculation

Tags: c, memory-layout, memory-footprint

Following is the output from size on a.out

```
text       data        bss        dec        hex    filename
2469324      45808    **9087820**    11602952     b10c08    a.out
```

When i total the size output on all individual obj and libraries used

```
text       data      bss     dec
2777237 44307   **23112**   2844656
```

I can understand that text size in actual executable is less than the total size (libraries + main.o), since actual executable will not contain the text part for unused functions inlibraries.

My Question is why bss section is huge (~9MB) in the final executable, where it is ~23k when i total the sum of bss sections of libraries and main.o.

How to find, where(files) is this huge bss sections allocated in executable.

I'm using ubuntu 13.04, gcc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `bss section is huge (~9MB)` ? where? in bytes like.

Comment: i'm expecting bss section in executable to match with sum of bss sections in libraries and objects used. but it is not matching. when i sum the bss sections of each libraries and main.o it comes aroung 23kB, where bss section on executable shows 9MB(as shown in first part).

Comment: the memory layout of your final executable is defined by the linker script. Do you use a custom one?
An unexpectedly large .bss section either indicates huge global variables, noncontiguous memory layout or might be caused by alignment requirements you didn't take into account.

Comment: @mfro: we are using gcc, we don't have any custom linker script. We have global variables, but i'm sure that should not consume 9MB. Is there any way to verify.

Comment: I'd start with `gcc ... -Wl,Map=mapfile` (let ld generate a cross reference and load map file). This should show you where your data explosion comes from.

Comment: Thank god, No, i have to say **Thanks mfro**. It seems i found the place where large bss section is used with map file. Let me complete and update.